# I did Kmeans with Matlab on my 3D data, the results are differnet from original 3D plot? Why

Tags: clustering, matlab, k-means, pattern-recognition

I have done Kmeans clustering on my data based on three main features. The main scatter plot is as below:

[image]

But when Kmeans clusters the data it seems that a part of data points are being flattened. I have put the clustering result from another viewpoint which seems to be weird:

[image: Clustering Results by Kmeans Method]

As seen the red cluster is flattened? I have no idea about the reason!!
Has anyone encountered with similar situation ever?

Comment: Are you sure your plotting code is correct? Also, this data set should cluster much better with DBSCAN.

Comment: Why do you think that DBSCAN is a better choice? I run the Kmeans code from Matlab function set, As far as I know the code is ok./I have written the code below:                                                                                                                                    %%%%%%%%  Kmeans code to obtain 3 clusters%%%%%%%%%                                                         ||    size Feats  
||    idx = kmeans(Feats,3,'MaxIter',10000,'Display','Iter','Replicates',201);

Comment: The data had arbitrarily shaped, density clusters. Not gaussians of the same size. Therefore, try DBSCAN. And since the coordinates changed, I assume your *visualization*  code is broken.